# Scalling Wordpress on Windows Azure:

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

I'm running a Wordpress multisite which in short periods every week experience a big number of users requiring more CPU + RAM.

I therefore wish to make use of Azure autoscale to turn on more instances if the demand are there, however is it possible to make a setup where the different instances share same storage and database? And if yes how could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported by out-of-the-box:

1. Goto "Web Sites" and add a new website from "Gallery".
2. Select "WordPress"
3. Follow the rest of the wizard.

The wizard allows you to create a MySQL database. The website runs as a cluster and uses a database which also runs on a cluster of servers (hosted by ClearDB).